# Qt codingstyle: how to name private variables

Tags: c++, qt, coding-style

I would like to know, what is the "best" way to name your private variables in a Qt c++ class?

I know that every company/person has its own preferences when it comes to coding style guidelines, but maybe you can give some examples I can choose from. At the moment I tent to prefix private variables with "my", which seems a bit silly. For example:

```
public: 
    bool setColor();
    QColor color();
private:
    QColor mycolor;
```

I did read http://wiki.qt.io/Qt_Coding_Style for reference, but unfortunately it did not cover this issue.

Comment: http://wiki.qt.io/Qt_Coding_Style#Declaring_variables

Comment: BЈовић: I don't understand your comment, I did read the document, as I already said in my question, but I cant see there anything about "private variables". My problem is: how to make it obvious in the sourcecode that this variable is only local readable compared to others global readable.

Comment: Private variables are variables after all, and the coding style for them is in the link you posted

Answer (score 3):

Qt itself uses encapsulation in "private class" (aka pImpl), so no additional naming convention is required.

As alternative, some prefer to choose special prefix like `m_`.